# Visualising one dimension in real/physical world.

Tags: physics, visualization

How can we visualize one-dimension in real/Physical world? Does any body have an example? Often people refer to one-dimension as motion being in a straight line. However motion in a straight line can be two dimensional. For Instance, The graph of $f(x)=x$, for every $x\epsilon \mathbb{R}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Motion in a straight line is still one-dimensional even if it is not parallel to an axis. Anyway, the main emergence in physical problems is as an extreme limit, in which the other dimensions exist but are somehow trivial. Typically this is an approximation of some kind (for example, fluid flow is never truly laminar) but such approximations can be useful anyway.

Comment: The graph of f(x)=x is drawn on a two dimensional graph; but, the line is still one dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the graph of $f(x) = x$, there is one line. It is diagonal, and it seems like it's going in the up-right direction, but it only has one direction in the sense that it cannot escape the line.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an ant stuck on a very thin wire.

Any straight line graphed on a plane.

Power lines in a picture.